# How to use Atomizr to convert Atom snippets into SublimeText completions?

Tags: sublime-text-3, atom-editor

I'm trying to use Atomizr (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Atomizr) to convert Atom's C++ snippets into SublimeText completions.

I have installed Atomizr in SublimeText using package-control and I've done the following:

**1)** Copied the snippets from github.com/atom/language-c/blob/master/snippets/language-c.cson to a .cson file.

**2)** Opened the file above using ST.

**3)** Ctrl+Shift+P and "Convert Atom snippets into SublimeText completions".

Sadly, after doing that, nothing happens. How do I go about using Atomizr?

EDIT:

Sublime-Text 3, version 3103;

Atomizr version 0.2.2;

EDIT2:

After re-installing everything, it worked. I now have a file with the following format:

```
    {
        "contents": "std::cout << \"${1:/* message */}\" << std::endl;",
        "trigger": "cout"
    },
```

However, that is not the format for sublime-text snippets, as far as I am aware, is it? I suppose I now need to change this to a .sublime-completions format (with  and all that).

Comment: Which version of Sublime Text? Which version of Atomizr? Do you use Package Control 3?

Comment: @idleberg, I've added that info to the OP: Sublime-Text 3, version 3103; Atomizr version 0.2.2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed there was a problem with the release tag for Atomizr v0.2.2. The version was identical to v0.2.1, which had a problem loading the package dependencies.

Upgrade to the latest version of Atomizr (v0.3.1). Since the package dependencies continue to cause minor hiccups, you might have to remove the package before installing it again and/or restart Sublime Text. If the problem persists, take a look at the console if there are any warnings about a missing package. Usually, it's the speg dependency causing trouble.

Also, since this is a very specific problem, feel free to create an [issue](https://github.com/idleberg/sublime-atomizr/issues) on GitHub!

Comment: I re-installed everything and it now works. Though the format is the format is different than .sublime-completions. Should this work as well? Or do I need to still edit it in order to be compatible with sublime?

Comment: What's different? I haven't had any problem converting the files, the only editing required is giving the file the correct extension (`.sublime-completions`)

Comment: The plugin creates completions, not snippets. But that's what you requested yourself in the first sentence of your question ;-)

Comment: I've done that as well and it does not work. I've given it the extension .sublime-completions, restarted sublime, opened a .cpp document and for example, "whil + tab" still doesn't give what it's supposed to (which is the while loop).

Comment: Your example from above is working for me. It's probably a scope exception, since Atom uses different [scope names](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/fca633438329cc5ae327). Otherwise, please create an issue on GitHub with a detailed exampled.

Comment: It was a scope problem, yes. I added "source.c++" and it now works. Might I ask one quick question? Is there any advantage of using snippets over auto-completions, or vice-versa?